# ValueError: time data 'X' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M' (match)

Tags: python, pandas, string-to-datetime, str-to-date

and I encountered a problem when I was using pandas.to_datetime to convert a column to datetime, could you help me to figure out why? Thank you.

[image]

I tried to change the format but I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Providing CODE instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community.it is one of the reasons that you get Downvote

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you have a row where the `Order Date` is literally `X`, you can ignore errors as in `to_date(df[...], format=..., errors='ignore')`